# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie in Generic Handler ashx

Tags: forms-authentication, ashx, formsauthentication, generic-handler

I have an Generic Handler where I would like to auto-login based on some querystrings.

But then I set FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Name, false), but HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated return false, and I can't redirect because of the limits set in web.config.

So how do I set FormsAuthentications in an .ashx-file?

Comment: Do you want to use that ashx as way to login?

Answer (score 1):

To perform a login using the FormsAuthentication module, you may want to just use the [RedirectFromLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) static method, which, under the covers:

1. prepares the authentication token;
2. encrypts it;
3. adds it to the cookie collection of the response;
4. performs the redirect to the required page (or the default one, as per your web.config).

Here is a short prototype for your handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // TODO: Determine the user identity

    var username = context.Request.QueryString["username"];

    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true);
}
```

If you are not comfortable by the way this method performs its job, you may do each activity in a manual way:

1. prepare a [FormsAuthenticationTicket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with the user name;
2. encrypt it by way of the [Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method;
3. add it to the [response Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies%28v=vs.80%29.aspx);
4. issue a [redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it as a location path in the web.config?

```
<configuration>
   <location path="foo.ashx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
   <location >
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```